# unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Tags: swift

I am new to SWIFT and trying to show some data into table view controller but when I press the button it shows the above error. Please correct me

import UIKit
var selectedPlace : Place!

class ShowPlaceTableTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var places : [Place]!

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    places = readPlaces()
     }

// MARK: - Table view data source



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return places.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! PlaceTableViewCell

    cell.countryLabel.text = places[indexPath.row].country
    cell.placeImageView.image = places[indexPath.row].picture
    
    

    return cell
}
func readPlaces() -> [Place]
{
    
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "places") != nil
    {
        var data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "places") as! Data
    let places = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as! [Place]
    return places
    }else
    {
        return [Place]()
    }
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedPlace = places[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: self)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Is your `PlaceTableViewCell` inside it's own `xib` separately OR is it inside the storyboard itself? You must register either a cell class or a nib before you try to dequeue the cell from tableView.

1. If it's inside the storyboard, then you can register the subclass to work with it.

```
tableView.register(PlaceTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PlaceTableViewCell")
```

2. If it's inside it's own xib separately, then you can register the `UINib` to work with it.

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "PlaceTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PlaceTableViewCell")
```

These need to be called once only, you can place these calls inside `viewDidLoad()`.

Now you can dequeue it like following -

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlaceTableViewCell") as! PlaceTableViewCell
```

##### Note : The `reuseIdentifier` must be same in following places -

1. storyboard (or xib)
2. at the time of registration `tableView.register...`
3. at the time of dequeue `tableView.dequeue...`